I want to auto check the checkbox and rerender the other components in visualforce page when a condition met in controller method
I have a Boolean method which checks the condition and return a Boolean value based on the condition result. I need to rendered this method in vf page and need to made checkbox field to be auto check and rerender and action the another components and method if return value is true.
When I am making checkbox auto check the action and rerender is not working since the checkbox is checked automatically. I just placed inputcheckbox, actionSupport tags in actionregion.
I want to inform that action and rerender is working, if the checkbox is changed to manual check type.
Please give me the solution, use any example which fulfill my requirements.
<apex: pageBlockSectionItem rendered="(!UpdateNonMigratedCheckbox)">

<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Case.fields. NonMigratedPolicyComplaint_c.label]" for="nonMigratedPolicy" />

<apex:actionRegion >

<apex: inputCheckbox id="nonMigratedPolicy" value=" {!checkbox}">

<apex:actionSupport action="{!callerRelationNonMigratedPolicy)" event="onload" rerender="caseInfo, caseContacts, callerDetails">

</apex: inputCheckbox>

</apex:actionRegion>

</apex: pageBlockSectionItem>

-----Method-----
public Boolean getUpdateNonMigratedCheckbox(){

checkbox=false;

if (theCase.Function c == 'General Insurance && theCase. Request Type == null){

checkbox=true;

}

return checkbox;

}


Hi Pavan, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], and take our quick [tour], if you haven't already. Please [edit] your question to include the code that you're trying to get working. This will allow us to provide you a specific answer that will directly address your question, instead of guessing about what you're trying to do.

Hi @sfdcfox, just updated code please check

First, do not write "side effects" into a getter, because the order of getters are not guaranteed. This is noted in the documentation.

It’s a best practice for getter methods to be idempotent, that is, to not have side effects. For example, don’t increment a variable, write a log message, or add a new record to the database. Visualforce doesn’t define the order in which getter methods are called, or how many times they might be called in the course of processing a request. Design your getter methods to produce the same outcome, whether they are called once or multiple times for a single page request.

Instead, update a Boolean value to show when Function__c or Request_Type__c changes.
public void setVisibilityForNonMigratedCheckbox() {
  Boolean oldValue = showNonMigratedCheckbox ?? false;
  showNonMigratedCheckbox = theCase.Function__c == 'General Insurance' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null;
  if(oldValue != showNonMigratedCheckbox) {
    checkbox = true;
  }
}

<apex:selectList value="{!theCase.Function__c}" ...
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setVisibilityForNonMigratedCheckbox}" /> ...
</apex:selectList>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!showNonMigratedCheckbox}"> ...

Also note that onload won't work with your apex:actionSupport. Try onchange instead:
<apex:actionSupport action="{!callerRelationNonMigratedPolicy}" event="onchange" rerender="caseInfo, caseContacts, callerDetails" />

Aside from this, you likely have additional problems with your code. I'm only calling out those problems I see with the given code, assuming that many of the errors regarding - versus =, () versus {}, etc are all just typos.

But I want to auto check the checkbox, if the condition met and do action and rerender automatically, when the checkbox auto checked. If I use onchange then I have to click on checkbox to do action and rerender.

@PavanKumarH Correct. Set the value you want when the rendered state changes, as demonstrated in this answer. Do not set the value in the getter, because it will be unreliable.

Which event type I have to use to
run action and rerender when the checkbox is automatically checked
